# How can I use Excel VBA to create pivot table by filtering based on cell value/list?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, pivot-table

Not a VBA expert so apologies from the start!

I have data on separate sheets for 2020, 2019, 2018 and 2017 in the following format:

Area        Outlet   Cost

California  SF       $1,000

Texas       Aus      $2,000

California  LA       $1,500

California  SF       $2,000

California  LA       $3,000

Texas       Aus      $4,000

This data will be used to create quarterly reports, comparing each years quarter to the previous years quarter, i.e. 2020 Q1 vs 2019 Q1 vs 2018 Q1 vs 2017 Q1.

I want to now use VBA to speed up this process.

**What I want my report to do:**

From a drop-down list I want to pick the area that I want to study, e.g. California. Then using a button I want to generate a pivot table that will aggregate the costs for each Outlet in that area in a column for each year 2020, 2019, 2018 and 2017 datasets.

I have a unique list created to remove duplicate Outlets (Table 5 in the code below) and so far using Macros I have been able to create the pivot table on a new sheet from the overall list, but I haven't been able to find a way that will allow me to filter before creating the pivot table.

Say cell A1 on Sheet 1 is where my list will be.

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

```
Application.Goto Reference:="Table5"



Dim wsNew As Worksheet



Set wsNew = Sheets.Add



ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_Book1!Table5"), Version:=6). _

    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTableCost" _

    , DefaultVersion:=6



    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost")

    .ColumnGrand = True

    .HasAutoFormat = True

    .DisplayErrorString = False

    .DisplayNullString = True

    .EnableDrilldown = True

    .ErrorString = ""

    .MergeLabels = False

    .NullString = ""

    .PageFieldOrder = 2

    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0

    .PreserveFormatting = True

    .RowGrand = True

    .PrintTitles = False

    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True

    .TotalsAnnotation = True

    .CompactRowIndent = 1

    .VisualTotals = False

    .InGridDropZones = False

    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True

    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = True

    .DisplayContextTooltips = True

    .ShowDrillIndicators = True

    .PrintDrillIndicators = False

    .DisplayEmptyRow = False

    .DisplayEmptyColumn = False

    .AllowMultipleFilters = True

    .SortUsingCustomLists = True

    .DisplayImmediateItems = True

    .ViewCalculatedMembers = True

    .FieldListSortAscending = False

    .ShowValuesRow = False

    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = True

    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow

End With



ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").PivotCache.RefreshOnFileOpen = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels



With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Table5].[Outlet]")

    .Orientation = xlRowField

    .Position = 1

End With



ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2020 Cost]"), "Sum of 2020 Cost"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2019 Cost]"), "Sum of 2019 Cost"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2018 Cost]"), "Sum of 2018 Cost"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2017 Cost]"), "Sum of 2017 Cost"



ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2020%]"), "Sum of 2020%"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2019%]"), "Sum of 2019%"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2018%]"), "Sum of 2018%"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableCost").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _

    "PivotTableCost").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of 2017%]"), "Sum of 2017%"
```

Comment: Have you considered using slicers? You could merge your data from each sheet beforehand and dynamically filter a single pivot table instead of creating a new one each time. [Slicers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d#:~:text=Create%20a%20slicer%20to%20filter,every%20field%20that%20you%20selected.)

Comment: That looks like it could do exactly as I wished, thank you :)